# How to write bytes to csv file as byte strings not integers?

Tags: python, csv

There is a list of bytes objects (each one is 4 bytes) that is returned as output of one code and I want to save it into a `.csv` file using `CSV` module and read it back later in another script. Here is the code that I have learnt from python's official documentation:

```
import struct
import csv

k   = 0x100000
rng = range(0, k)
x1 = [b''] * k
x = 0xffffffff

for i in rng:
    x1[i]   = struct.pack("<L", x)
    x -= 1

print(x1[0])              # b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'

List = x1

with open("test.csv", 'w', newline='') as rF:
    wr = csv.writer(rF, dialect='excel')
    for i in List:
        wr.writerow(i)
```

When looking inside the created `test.csv` using notepad, instead of a column of byte strings I see 4 columns of 8-bit integers. Few first lines of `test.csv` are:

```
255,255,255,255
254,255,255,255
253,255,255,255
252,255,255,255
251,255,255,255
250,255,255,255
       .
       .
       .
```

What am I doing wrong that this is happening? Is there a way to get a csv file with one column of byte strings? for example:

```
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
b'\xfe\xff\xff\xff'
b'\xfd\xff\xff\xff'
          .
          .
          .
```

Actually I do not care how are my bytes stored in a csv. I just care to have them back into a list of bytes using `csv.reader` in another script and want the loading process be the quickest possible.

Comment: `CSV` can't save binary data. Think about using raw `binary` file instead of `csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do.

```
import pandas as pd
import struct

k   = 0x100000
rng = range(0, k)
x1 = [b''] * k
x = 0xffffffff

for i in rng:
    x1[i]   = struct.pack("<L", x)
    x -= 1

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["data"] = x1
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False, header=None)
```

This will output file in bytes. Sample output

```
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
b'\xfe\xff\xff\xff'
b'\xfd\xff\xff\xff'
b'\xfc\xff\xff\xff'
b'\xfb\xff\xff\xff'
```

You can use pandas instead of csv, to read the file back.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
```

Alternative

```
with open("test.csv", "wb") as f:
    for i in x1:
        f.write(i)
        f.write('\n'.encode('utf-8'))

# Reading file
y = []
with open("test.csv", "rb") as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        y.append(i.replace('\n'.encode('utf-8'), "".encode("utf-8")))
pprint(y[:10])
```

Output

```
[b'\xff\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xfe\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xfd\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xfc\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xfb\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xfa\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xf9\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xf8\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xf7\xff\xff\xff',
 b'\xf6\xff\xff\xff']
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without having to use a third party library?!

Comment: @PouJa Updated the answers with alternative. See if that works.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping I will definitely accept the answer when I make sure it works. Just wondering how to recover it to a list of bytes items in another script!?

Comment: @PouJa I have updated the answer for reading and a slight change in Alternative write approach.